# Invariant Tensor in spin representations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

Exercise 1.9 of the book Covariant LQG by Rovelli and Vidotto reads:

If we raise the index of the Pauli matrices with $\epsilon$ we obtain the 2-index spinors $(\sigma_i)^{AB} = (\sigma_i)^A_C\epsilon^{CB}$. Show that these are invariant tensors in the representation $\frac12\otimes\frac12\otimes1$.

In what sense are they invariant? (Under SU(2) action?) How are these $2\times2$ arrays even living in a $3\times 2\times 2 = 12$ dimensional Hilbert space?

Comment: Maybe $i$ is also an index? But it explicitly says they're 2 indexed

Comment: What else would $i$ be? It’s an index, but not a spinor index.

Comment: Yes @Ghoster, that's what I meant. Does he mean that for each $i$, these are 2-indexed invariant tensors?

Comment: Since he talks about the representation $\frac12\otimes\frac12\otimes1$, he must be thinking of $(\sigma_i)^{AB}$ as one 3-index tensor. The indices of a tensor don’t all have to be for the same space. $A$ and $B$ are for spinor space; $i$ is for regular 3D space. (BTW, I know nothing about LQG.)

Comment: You need to work out the transformations on $A$, $B$, and $i$ and show that combined they do nothing.

Comment: Correct, it was the 3 index matrix and it is indeed invariant. I'll close the question.

Comment: You’re allowed to answer your own question if you want.